# Test password complexity without creating a user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to check if a particular password string passes sql server/windows password validation/complexity rules (that is be valid for creating a user) using SQL but **without** creating a user ?

Thx!

Comment: So you can raise a different error? Why? If user creation fails, what's the difference? If it succeeds, you can just roll it back? The whole concept here makes me nervous - why are you holding on to a user's chosen password long enough to make some kind of determination about it?

Comment: I need to check it on a web client registration form which let's a user register with username/password but does not create a user until an admin approves it

Comment: So try (with a dummy username) and roll it back if it succeeds. Or build validation into your client side that has *stronger* rules than the underlying policy.

Comment: The validation has to be the same. Yes my question is if it can be dome without the ugly dummy user which is ugly ...

Comment: How are you storing passwords before approval? If you're using reversible encryption or plain text, you've created a HUGE security hole.  Instead, create the user, but disable it, pending approval. The approval process can either activate the user or drop it.

Comment: Also, this sounds like it's not a database question, per se. SQL just enforces AD's password policy. If you want to check the password against the AD policy, you don't need SQL Server for that.

Comment: And if the validation has to be the same because you want to enforce the passwords to be the same, maybe you shouldn't be creating SQL auth logins in the first place. Why don't you just add the login from Windows, and then they only have one password to manage from AD. You can still disable it until approved, as Andy suggested.

Comment: You could use a _stronger_ complexity standard.  Like, must be 28 characters and consist of !0 followed by every letter of the alphabet in any order except that one, that one, and that one.

Answer (score 2):

The **`enforce password policy`** setting for a SQL Server Login is basically a set of rules. These are as follows:

> ## Password Complexity
>
> Password complexity policies are designed to deter brute force attacks by increasing the number of possible passwords. When password complexity policy is enforced, new passwords must meet the following guidelines:
>
> - The password does not contain the account name of the user.
> - The password is at least eight characters long.
> - The password contains characters from three of the following four categories:
>
>   - Latin uppercase letters (A through Z)
>   - Latin lowercase letters (a through z)
>   - Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
>   - Non-alphanumeric characters such as: exclamation point (!), dollar sign ($), number sign (#), or percent (%).
>
> Passwords can be up to 128 characters long. You should use passwords that are as long and complex as possible.

**Reference:** [Password Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy) (Microsoft Docs)

So basically you could program your web form to check for the complexity of a given password according to the above rules.

There are a couple of questions over on **Stack Overflow** that summaries possibilities of using REGEX or Java to check the password complexity:

- [Complex password Regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3466850/1820861) and [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3466868/1820861)
- [Regex to validate password strength](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5142103/1820861) and [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5142164/1820861)

Good luck.

Comment: As a user I don't get on with password complexity rules.  Do you think that requiring punctuation increases our password inventing inspiration?  OK this isn't your idea so don't take personally: Ihateyou!  Istillhateyou!  Ihateyouforever!  On the other hand, evil developers are working tirelessly on superior password guessers.  (So are the brave engineers of Five Eyes.)  These days I use some random letters, one uppercase - I recently gave up vowels - a couple of digits, and punctuation only if I must.  Once I see the letters I may invent a memorable phrase to represent them.

Comment: I agree with you. Passwords are no long the best solution. Pass-phrases are the way to go. Easier to memorise and to handle. Store them in a safe place (KeePass) and off you go. The standard Windows compexity rules are a starting point. `ThisIsMyNewP@ssw0rd4M.crosoft` is easy to remember and meats the standard requirements. Password/-phrase algorithms are only as good as the programmer behind the input field.